# Formatting data in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to format a dataset in a json format by adding brackets separated by commas. The goal is to export it to a csv. The dataset has holes in some fields for some records and I get errors if I import them directly.

I have this line

```
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
```

But I got this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-923cc05f5de6> in <module>()
----> 1 data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Comment: Well I think a JSON shouldn't have sequences like `[,`

Comment: Please, provide example of `data` content. Also, why don't you want to use built in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski it doesn't result in `[,`, data is joined first by `','.join(data)` then enclosed in brackets.

Comment: map(str,data) may fix it, i do not know the "data", though

Comment: For your code to work, `data` would have to be sequence of strings. Obviously it isn't. Please edit your question and describe its format.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Python 3, I presume.

In Python 3, there are two string formats: [str (sequences of Unicode code points)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) and [bytes (sequences of bytes)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). For some reason (like having read the file in binary mode), you ended up with `bytes` instead of strings in your `data` object. These can neither be used as arguments to `','.join` nor passed to `json.dumps`:

```
>>> data = [b'abc', b'def']
>>> data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: b'abc' is not JSON serializable
```

You must first convert your bytes to unicode strings. If you already know the encoding (it's usually UTF-8), you can write e.g.:

```
>>> data = [d.decode('utf-8') for d in data]
>>> data
['abc', 'def']
```

And then use either string joining or (preferably) [the JSON library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to convert them to a JSON string.

---

**EDIT**: One reason why the data read from a file might be kept in bytes instead of Unicode is when you read from a file with the binary flag set, i.e. `open(filename, 'rb')` instead of `open(filename 'r')`. See [the `open` function reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more information on how to change the default encoding when reading the file.

So, in the optimal case, the data is read from a text file into Unicode strings:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

And then converted to json:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Here's a format of a record in my dataset. I'm basically trying to convert it into a nice dataframe or simply export to a csv. But I've been getting errors in python. I pasted the data on vrious online conversion tools but none worked. {"var1":"100027","var2":1437486945732,"var3":1437488538170,"var4":"Op/9.8 (A; OM/6.5.27452/37.6066; U; en) P/2.12.423 V/12.16","var5":"/AF","var6":"/1","var7":"/186","var8":"/76","var9":"/1","var10":"www.google.com","var11":"http://www.google.com/","var12":"196.46.245.127"}

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the data. What command did you type to receive the representation you just pasted? Can you do `print(data)` and paste the output of that here instead?

Comment: Thanks. Here's my code. I didn't write it from scratch and tried editing it with my limited knowledge of python.  
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)

data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
print (data_json_str)

df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
      print index
      if row[9] == u'\U0010ffff':
 row[9] = 'emptyEntry'
 df.ix[index,9] = 'emptyEntry'
      print str(df.ix[index,9])

df.to_csv("data-clean1.csv", index=False)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to type the code with the appropriate breaks and indents. I can send it to you directly if it's easier. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np


with open('data-2015-7-21.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)

data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
print (data_json_str)

df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
      print index
      if row[9] == u'\U0010ffff':
 row[9] = 'emptyEntry'
 df.ix[index,9] = 'emptyEntry'
      print str(df.ix[index,9])

df.to_csv("data-clean1.csv", index=False)`